# jQuery for each count up by .5

Tags: jquery

How can I count up in jQuery in a for each function by just 0.5 instead of 1?

```
$(".item").each( function(i) {
  console.log(i+0.5);
});
```

At the moment this goes up by .5 + 1. Can I only jump up by 0.5 each time? The logic as to why I want to do this is because I'm setting an animation delay for each item within a certain element. So for each item I want to increase the delay via this function.

Comment: This will help you understanding what is going wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Interesting theoretical question, but in practice, what are you trying to accomplish with this logic? FYI - I didn't downvote, likely reason is your question was too simple or didn't show much effort.

Comment: @TimLewis Updated with a little more info. Not sure for the downvote? I thought it was a legit question...

Answer (score 0):

As per the doc of [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/), the first argument of the function is an integer representing the index. So, what you want to do actually is

```
$(".item").each( function(i) {
  console.log(i*0.5);
});
```

Comment: Which is essentially the same as nevermind's comment, but operation inverted. :P

Comment: Yes, sorry for him/her, I was in the process of adding the doc page to link to my answer, so I took a little more time to write it than he/she did :)